# Deep routing works with angular 5 app on tomcat but direct routing doesnt

Tags: angular, tomcat, angular5

I have deployed my angular 5 apps on tomcat. The deep link routing like (localhost:8080/emp/1) works fine but direct link routing like(localhost:8080/aboutUs) doesn't work.

It throws a 404.

I am creating my build and copying all the files from dist folder to the tomcat webapps/root folder and created a .htaccess file mentioned under https://angular.io/guide/deployment.

Comment: Have you set it up in tomcat so that it redirects 404 error to `index.html` as well?

Comment: Yes , I have created a .htaccess file under root folder and added the below in the same -<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c="">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</ifmodule>  
Do i need to add anything else ?

Comment: Did you deploy with "ng build --prod " or "ng build" ?

Comment: ng build --prod

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't use `href`. I was using `<a href` for direct links and `<a router` link for deep links. Once I changed every link to `<a routerLink` everything works.